# Unmarshall json reference types

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I'm trying to write a working example to test "Reference Types" section of [this link](https://blog.golang.org/json-and-go).

But I'm unable to understand how this should work. The example I'm trying to write without success is provided below, just for reference:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "encoding/json"
)

type Foo1 struct {
    Val     int
}

type Foo2 struct {
    Name    string
}

type IncomingMsg struct {
    F1 *Foo1
    F2 *Foo2
}

func main() {
    b := []byte(`{"F1" : {"Val":13}}`)
//  b := []byte(`{"F2" : {"Name":"Hello"}}`)

    var msg IncomingMsg

    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &msg)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if msg.F1 != nil {
        fmt.Println(msg.F1.Val)
    }

    if msg.F2 != nil {
        fmt.Println(msg.F2.Name)
    }
}
```

Can some of you with more experience with Go help with this issue?

EDIT: The provided test has been updated, now is working as expected. Thank you Mr Adam for the answer provided, it helped me a lot to understand this issue! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The json you have posted in your example looks like it is missing `F1` in the body?

https://play.golang.org/p/Fl-lhH2y3X

`` b := []byte(`{"F1":{"Val":13}}`) ``

Comment: It works, thank you very much, Mr. Adam! :) Then, It is supposed you need to include the field name in the JSON being decoded to use this useful pattern referenced in documentation? I though you could do that in a more generic way.

Comment: @aicastell, this is how all JSON deserializers work. It is just standard JSON to concrete type mapping

Comment: Not all of them use this suggested pattern, I am familiarized with C development and after using cJSON, jasmine and other C based deserializers, this feature was completely new for me.